# How to pass id from method defined in Typescript file to HTML button in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm currently working on an Angular project and I'm trying to implement a feature where clicking a button triggers the deletion of a specific entity by passing its ID to a TypeScript method. However, I'm having trouble passing the ID from the TypeScript method to the HTML button to trigger the deletion event.

Here's my current setup:

HTML:

```
<button mat-raised-button class="btn" color="warn" (click)="deleteStaffByID()">
Delete
```

TypeScript:

```
deleteStaffByID(id: any) {
console.log("Delete working!");
try {
    this.staffService.deleteStaffDataByID(id).subscribe(data => {
        this.dataSource = data;
        alert("Staff deleted successfully!");
        // this.listStaff();
        console.log(data);
    });
} catch(err) {
    console.log("error in deleting the staff", err);
}
```

}

I'm unsure how to pass the ID from the HTML button to the deleteStaffByID() method in TypeScript. I've tried various approaches, including defining a different parameter in the TypeScript method, but none have been successful.

Could someone please guide me on how to properly pass the ID from the HTML button to the TypeScript method in this scenario? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: please share more HTML code, plz show us all places where id is used!

Comment: this button will be the first element in which i will be passing the id...rest is an edit form...and i have added the delete functionality inside the edit form functionality.

Comment: plz share how id is defined, is it `this.id` or are you running an `ngFor` for each form element?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you generally do it with using `NgForOf`

Note the `let-item`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForOf } from '@angular/common';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [NgForOf],
  template: `
    <ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="ids">
      <button (click)="onIdClick(item)">click {{ item }}</button>
    </ng-template>
  `,
})
export class ContainerComponent {
  ids = [1, 2, 3, 4];

  onIdClick(id: number) {
    console.log(id);
  }
}
```

Comment: thankyou @Filip but this wasn't the solution that i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass id into deleteStaffByID() function as below:
Template Code:

```
<table>
<tr *ngFor="let staff of staffArray">
    <td>{{ staff.name }}</td>
    <td><button mat-raised-button class="btn" color="warn" 
    (click)="deleteStaffByID(staff.id)">Delete
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: actually my button is not inside the table , therefore i want to pass the directly to the button..help me if you have a solution

Comment: Delete function need id to perform delete action but if your button is outside of table then you can add checkbox while displaying against each rows.
select the checkbox which staff you want to delete and while selecting store that staff id into an array.
Then while clicking on button loop that stored staff id array and perform the action .